# Knockout Js Custom Dictionary Binding MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have come across another problem, which could be minor.

I have the following structure now:

[Code for ViewModel]

```
public class ResultModel
{
    public Dictionary<Person, List<Person>> dictPeople { get; set; }
    public string dictPeopleJson { get; set; }
    public ResultModel()
    {
        dictPeople = new Dictionary<Person, List<Person>>();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

[Code For Controller]

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var p1 = new Person();
        p1.ID = 100;
        p1.Name = "John";
        p1.Surname = "Smith";

        var p2 = new Person();
        p2.ID = 104;
        p2.Name = "John";
        p2.Surname = "Harvard";

        var p3 = new Person();
        p3.ID = 109;
        p3.Name = "Kate";
        p3.Surname = "Robinson";

        var p4 = new Person();
        p4.ID = 116;
        p4.Name = "Kate";
        p4.Surname = "Smith";

        var p5 = new Person();
        p5.ID = 130;
        p5.Name = "Kate";
        p5.Surname = "Jane";

        List<Person> lstPerson1 = new List<Person>();
        lstPerson1.Add(p1);
        lstPerson1.Add(p2);


        List<Person> lstPerson2 = new List<Person>();
        lstPerson1.Add(p3);
        lstPerson2.Add(p4);
        lstPerson2.Add(p5);

        var vm = new ResultModel();
        vm.dictPeople.Add(new Person() {ID = 001, Name = "John", Surname = "Family"}, lstPerson1);
        vm.dictPeople.Add(new Person() {ID = 002, Name = "Kate", Surname = "Family"}, lstPerson2);
        vm.dictPeopleJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm.dictPeople, Formatting.Indented);
        vm.dictPeople = null;
        return View(vm);
}
```

[Code for CSHTML]

```
<h2>Results</h2>
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'tblResult', foreach: dictPeopleJson() }"></tbody>
</table>
<script id="tblResult" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="foreach: key">
            <table>
                <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Surname"></td>
            </table>
        </td>        
        <td>
            <table data-bind="foreach: value">
                <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Surname"></td>
            </table>    
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ResultModel = function(m) {
        var self = this;       
        self.dictPeopleJson = ko.observableArray(mapDictionaryToArray(m), function(person) {
            var per = new Person(person);
            return per;
        });
    };

    var Person = function(person) {
        var self = this;
        self.ID = ko.observable(person.Id);
        self.Name = ko.observable(person.Name);
        self.Surname = ko.observable(person.Surname);
    };

    function mapDictionaryToArray(dictionary) {
        var result = [];
        for (var key in dictionary) {
            if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                result.push({ key: key, value: dictionary[key] }); 
            }  
        }

        return result;
    }

    var data = @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
    var dataFromServer = ko.utils.parseJson(data.dictPeopleJson);

    console.log(dataFromServer);  
    ko.applyBindings(new ResultModel(dataFromServer));

    console.log("apply binding");
</script>
```

I am trying to get the display such as:

```
001 John Family     100 John Smith  104 John Harvard

002 Kate Family     109 Kate Robinson   116 Kate Smith ... etc
```

However the output is returning with just the last row binding (and not displaying the key part of the dictionary),

```
116 Kate    Smith

130 Kate    Jane
```

The values for the John family are lost, the array only contains values for Kate's family

Why is this happening please? Once the conversion to a json string is being done, all values are being shown in the string, but the console window only shows the kate family (last item in the dictionary)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please go debug with this line

vm.dictPeople = null;

It suppose to not there